make git-cliff produce commit list per tag
I want to have a changelog produced by git-cliff. I managed to make that happen in my gitlab pipeline whenever I create a release. I issue the command git-cliff --tag $releaseNumber. However, whenever I do that, the generated document has one chapter on level 2 and lists all commits like here:
# Changelog

All notable changes to this project will be documented in this file.

## [2.0.8] - 2024-07-05

### Bug Fixes

- fix 1
- fix 2

### Features

- feature 1
- feature 2

though the release 2.0.8 had only feature 2 as a new commit.
and so on so that each chapter lists only the commits that were new since the last release build. How can I achieve that? Many thanks in advance!
What I want to have instead would look like this:
# Changelog

All notable changes to this project will be documented in this file.

## [2.0.8] - 2024-07-05

### Features

- feature 2

## [2.0.7] 2024-06-31

### Bug fixes

- fix 2

### Features

- feature 1

